# Blackjack Background Image in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm trying to set a blackjack table as my background, as I'm creating a blackjack game. I can't figure out how to write the code, the blackjack3.gif image is in the SRC file with the .java file.

Current code:

```
`import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("blackjack3.gif").getImage());
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}



public class BlackJack {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("BlackJack");
    // JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
    // ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(blackjack3.gif);

    MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
    myFrame.add(canvas);

    myFrame.setSize(1200,604);

    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}`
```

Just need some help on what to do.

Answer (score 1):

> the blackjack3.gif image is in the SRC file with the .java file.

It needs to be on the classpath. So that would be where your class file is, not the source file.

Or you can try using `ImageIO.read(...)` to load the image. You will get an error if the file can't be loaded.

```
g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

Its possible the image has not been fully read when the painting method is invoked.

You should be using:

```
g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this); // note the "this"
```

The image will notify the component to repaint itself when it is fully loaded.

Also, read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples and better ways to load the image.

The demo code will show you how to better structure your code so the GUI is created on the Event Dispatch Thread which is important as all Swing components should be created/modified on the EDT.